# Nuget package verification is taking too long on a build machine

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nexus, nuget-package-restore

I have a build step in my CI pipeline where I restore the NuGet packages for my solution. I am retrieving my NuGet packages from a NuGet hosted repository on Sonatype Nexus. The package restore itself is running smooth enough, but it hangs in a step where it takes almost 2 to 3 minutes to verify some packages(in this case packages provided by Microsoft). The build agent where I have this restore done does not have internet access. And that's why I am also using a NuGet proxy on my Sonatype Nexus.
For example the step that it gets hanged on is:

> PackageSignatureVerificationLog: PackageIdentity:
>   Microsoft.Owin.3.1.0 Source: ...nuget\packages\
>   PackageSignatureValidity: True

I have considered adding a list of trusted-signers to the nuget configuration of my builds. But since my machine does not have internet access, this wouldn't be very helpful. As described in the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-trusted-signers

As described in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file
I also tried setting the `signitureValidationMode` to `<add key="signatureValidationMode" value="accept" />` which in this case will verify the packages by default. Even though this is the default case, and accepts them if it does not succeeds to connect. But this does not change the speed of my NuGet restore.

Besides opening up network access for all the NuGet verification URLs my solution would need.

Is there a way that I can set the NuGet configuration to not verify the certificates of the NuGet packages in an offline mode for my build agent?

Comment: I'm not sure about not verifying, but you may be able to reduce the connection timeout.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă, thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it if there isn't any other option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some digging around I found the following [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3028).

Which explains the possible slow down issue that might occur on an offline machine(such as a build agent) and a possible solution.

The issue can be resolved by implementing the Environment variable `NUGET_CERT_REVOCATION_MODE` to `offline`.

```
NUGET_CERT_REVOCATION_MODE = 'offline'
```

In a tool as Jenkins, you can declare it in the environment variables, or you can run a command on the build machine to set the environment variable.